# How do i set custom rule to windows 10 firewall to alert if any .cs file extension is uploaded?

Tags: networking, windows-10

How do i set custom rule to windows 10 firewall to alert if any .cs file extension is uploaded ?

please suggest multiple options.

Does any free/low cost firewall allows this without writing script ?

Comment: @karlo - please remember to only make significant updates. If the only issue is capitalisation, please don't bother.

Answer (score 2):

If the connection is over HTTPS, which most likely it is going by [your previous question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/167742/can-win-10-system-log-files-tell-me-about-any-cs-file-transfer-to-personal-goog), you can't alert on this at all. This honestly feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're looking for technical solutions to identify data exfiltration (essentially [DLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_loss_prevention_software)) in response to a problem that is *entirely not technical*.

You've observed a developer copying source code to a personal drive - something they probably shouldn't have done. Your response to that should not be to enact surveillance against your employees, but to speak to that employee directly. If you have a HR department, get them involved. Giving them the benefit of the doubt, they could've been trying to do some work from home later, or intending to share it with a colleague who wasn't in the office that day. You need to understand what's happening before you charge off on the assumption of malintent.

This is also a good time to assess your internal policies. Are USB drives allowed? Do you have an internal policy around data security? Have all of your employees read and signed it? Do you have an action plan for data breaches, and does it cover accidental and malicious exposure of trade secrets by employees? Do you have auditing and centralised logging where appropriate? Are laptops encrypted with FDE? Have your employees signed NDAs? All of these things are important.